# Get ahcResponse from Play WS

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, asynchttpclient

I had this:

```
class RichResponse(future: Future[WSResponse]) {

  def failIfNot(statuses: Int*)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext) = {
    future.map { response =>
      if(statuses.contains(response.status)) {
        response
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad HTTP response for %s: %s".format(
          response.ahcResponse.getUri, response.status))
      }
    }
  }

}

object Implicits {

  implicit def responseToRichResponse(future: Future[WSResponse]) = new RichResponse(future)

}
```

The usage was like this:

```
WS.url("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask").failIfNot(OK)
```

---

But after upgrading from 2.1 to 2.3, `achResponse` is no longer present. How to can I get the underlying (and more complete) response object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started reading the source, an it appears that

```
response.underlying[NingWSResponse].ahcResponse
```

would be the new way to do this.

Doesn't seem very typesafe....